# bounded linear operators is B(X,Y) is complete if Y is complete

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

QUESTION#1 is why he required that the space Y is complete not only the range of the operators is complete?

QUESTION#2

In the proof of this theorem :

i take a cauchy sequence {Tn} from B(X,Y) and proved that for each x in X, {Tn(x)} is a cauchy sequence and since Y is complete this sequence {Tn(x)} has a limit which we can denote by $s_x$ 
and we can check that the elements {$s_x$ : x in X } satisfy the properties of a linear transformation so we can define T:X to Y by T(x)=$s_x$ and then check that T defines a bounded linear map

my question is in this part:is the following proof is true for proving that T defines a "bounded " linear map 
since Tn(x) convergent to T(x)
then for every epsoln >0 there exist no in N :n>no implies ||Tn(x)-T(x)||< epsoln 
then can i say then that Tn-T is bounded and since Tn is bounded then T is bounded

Answer (score 1):

I assume we're talking about normed linear spaces here, and (for convenience) real scalars.

1) If $Y$ is not complete, there is a Cauchy sequence $y_n$ in $Y$ that has no limit there.  Take linear operators $T_n$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $T_n 1 = y_n$. 
Then these form a Cauchy sequence in $B(\mathbb R, Y)$ with no limit.

2) I'm not sure I understand your question, but pointwise convergence ($T_n x \to Tx$ for all $x$) does not in general imply convergence in norm.  You really need 
uniform estimates.

Comment: i mean only that if he required that the range of the operators is complete i will be enough

Comment: But which operators?  What result are you trying to prove?

Comment: In my example, each operator has a range that is complete (a one-dimensional space is always complete).

Comment: i just think he can write the theorem in the following form "Bounded linear operators B(X,Y) is complete if the range of the all bounded linear operators is complete"

Comment: You could say, if $T_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $B(X,Y)$ and there is a complete subspace $Z$ of $Y$ that contains the ranges of all $T_n$, then $T_n$ has a limit in $B(X,Y)$.

Comment: But if you want the conclusion to be $B(X,Y)$ is complete, then you are talking about **all** the bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$, and "if the range of the bounded linear operators is complete" doesn't make sense.

Comment: first in the proof we take a cauchy sequence {An} from B(X,Y) this means that for any epsoln >0 there is some N such that for all m,n>N ||An-Am||<epsoln This implies for any fixed vector x in X that ||An(x)-Am(x)||=||(An-Am)(x)||<||An-Am||||x||<epsoln||x|| or that the sequence {An(x)} is a cauchy sequence in Y and since Y is banach it has a limit HERE IS THE POINT if only thee range of all the bounded linear operators is complete then the sequence will also has a limit

Comment: What do you mean by "the range of all the bounded linear operators is complete"? "Every member of $B(X,Y)$ has a complete range"?  But this is generally not the case, and would not work: see my example again. "There is some complete linear subspace $Z$ of $Y$ such that every bounded linear operator from $X$ to $Y$ has its range in $Z$"? OK, but it's not hard to show that $Z$ would have to be all of $Y$.